# React won't import my module "Module not found: Can't resolve "

Tags: reactjs

React is not resolving my component import into my YouTubeApp.js.
It seems silly, i have other components in my react app that I'm able to import with no issues but this one in particular i can't get it imported.

Github: https://github.com/JAlonsoHdz/React_UnsplashClientApp/tree/master/src/components

Additional context, YouTubeApp.js is currently imported in my index.js with no issues. I'm using react routing imported in the index.js and links and the route links sucessfully to YouTubeApp.js. The problem arise whenver I try to import ANY component into YouTubeApp.js i get the Cannot resolve 'component name' error, without any imports the component YouTubeApp.js works fine.

I have validated the correct path, the name of the component.

YouTubeApp.js

```
import React from 'react';
import Other from './components/other';


class YouTubeApp extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (<p>test</p>

        );
    }
}

export default YouTubeApp;
```

And this is my component I'm trying to import:

```
import React from 'react';

class Other extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <div clasNames="ui container">test!</div>           
            );
    }
}

export default Other;
```

I need to nest at least a few levels down more components but this issue blocking.

Comment: Show the directory structure. For example if the first script is `src/YouTubeApp.js` then you're trying to include either `src/components/other.js` or `src/components/other/index.js`.

Comment: Doesn't `other` have a js extension?  
`import Other from './components/other';`

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I actually i found out I was adding an extra folder I changed it to "./other" and it worked. I feel so dumb man lol.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at your GitHub repository, it appears that YouTubeApp.js and other.js are both in the "components" directory. Therefore when in YouTubeApp.js (or any other component in your "components" directory) your import should be:

```
import Other from './other';
```

Comment: Thanks Ryan, that was it. Man, i was over complicating thinking there was something else! Appreciate your help!